# Keycloak configuration for MFA for the 1st-time users

Tags: keycloak

I am asked to configure keycloak (v6.0.0, I know it is very old) to require MFA for the 1st-time users only.

After looking at the reference and consulting ChatGpt, I have realised the "for the 1st-time users" part is not supported by Keycloak out-of-box when Keycloak is used as an authenticator (instead of relying on IDP for authentication)

Do I understand this correctly?

Thanks

John Zhu @ Majesco